# How to remove/replace native splash logo in android 12 in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-test

As we know that in flutter we can set custom logo or image in native splash screen that comes white by default. but in android 12 there is default option that it comes with launcher icon in place of white screen at the time of app launch. How can we replace that icon?

Comment: Support this question. Android 12 made a splash screen mandatory, but we cannot change how it looks (only allowed to change color?). The answer below, is NOT an answer, just a RTFM reply which I find everywhere online about this topic. If there is anyone who has a real answer to this question, I'd love to know!